# Using multiple values with strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']...)

Tags: php

another simple thing that's got me stuck:

I'm using the following to check on the current url and select a div class dependent on the result:

```
$checkit = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
... 
<li "; if(strstr($checkit,'welcome')) { echo "class='active_tab'"; }...
```

What I want to be able to do is also check if the url includes other words which would also require that same 'li' item to be given the 'active_tab' class, but i can't figure out the format. Something like this, although obviously this doesn't work:

```
<li "; if(strstr($checkit,'welcome', 'home', 'yourprofile')) { echo "class='active_tab'"; }...
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this by comparing with the URL? What if the URL changes in the future?

Comment: Just pass in a get variable into the url and check against that instead. What you're doing right now is not maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I *know* there's a better way but stop-gap fix would be:

```
$searchStrings = array('welcome','home','yourprofile');
$stringFound = false;
foreach($searchStrings as $checkString)
{
  if(strstr($checkit, $checkString))
  {
    $stringFound = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Then use `$stringFound` to change your output.

Edit 1: Switched `continue`for `break` thanks ZombieHunter (It's late -_-)

Edit 2: Alternatively you can use a regular expression (though I think that's overkill here)

```
if(preg_match('/(welcome|home|your profile)/',$checkit))
{
 // Do your stuff here
}
```

But this is not as expressive (easier to read and extend an array) and if those values start piling up its easier to hook the array into some storage like DB query.

Comment: I think you mean `break`, not `continue`